# Python3 syntax in Lowest common ancestor

Tags: python-3.x, lowest-common-ancestor

Classic problem of LCA in BT: Given a Binary Tree find the lowest common ancestor.
I found a Python2 solution but don't know how to fix it in Python3.

```
# This is Python2, but having error in Python3 such that 
# parent += node if all(subs) else max(subs),
# TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'`

# lca.py
class Solution:
    def lowestCommonAncestor(self, root, p, q):
        answer = []
        stack = [[root, answer]]

        while stack:
            top = stack.pop()
            (node, parent), subs = top[:2], top[2:]

            if node in (None, p, q):
                parent += node,
            elif not subs:
                stack += top, [node.right, top], [node.left, top]    
            else:
                parent += node if all(subs) else max(subs),     # this is the problem in Python3
        return answer[0]

s = Solution()
root = tree.create_tree3()
p = tree.find(root, 6)
q = tree.find(root, 1)
print(f'p = {p}, q = {q}')

lca = s.lowestCommonAncestor(root, p, q)

print(f"lca = {lca}")

# tree.py
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, val, left=None, right=None):
        self.val = val
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.val)

def find(root, val):
    if root is None:
        return None

    if root.val == val:
        return root

    left = find(root.left, val)
    right = find(root.right, val)

    if left is not None:
        return left
    else:
        return right

"""
                3
         5              1
     6      2         0   8
           7 4
"""
def create_tree3():
    n3 = TreeNode(3)
    n5 = TreeNode(5)
    n1 = TreeNode(1)
    n6 = TreeNode(6)
    n2 = TreeNode(2)
    n0 = TreeNode(0)
    n8 = TreeNode(8)
    n7 = TreeNode(7)
    n4 = TreeNode(4)

    n3.left, n3.right = n5, n1
    n5.left, n5.right = n6, n2
    n1.left, n1.right = n0, n8
    n2.left, n2.right = n7, n4

    return n3
```

I'm a newbie of Python3 and trying to fix this error in Python3, and I'm trying below, but not working.

```
class Solution:
    def lowestCommonAncestor(self, root, p, q):
        answer = []
        stack = [[root, answer]]

        while stack:
            top = stack.pop()
            (node, parent), subs = top[:2], top[2:]

            if node in (None, p, q):
                parent += node,
            elif not subs:
                stack += top, [node.right, top], [node.left, top]   
            else:
                if subs[0] and subs[1]:
                    parent += node
                else:               # not sure how to fix the below part which is not working either
                    if subs[0] and not subs[1]:
                        parent += subs[0]
                    elif not subs[0] and subs[1]:
                        parent += subs[1]
                    elif not subs[0] and not subs[1]:
                        parent += None

        return answer[0]
```

Comment: It would help to have a binary tree to test your code on. Does it fail for any binary tree? How far does it make it through the tree before it fails? My guess is that it is failing in the `max(subs)` where `subs` must eventually contain two `None` values.

Comment: @Tyberius right, I added a full code for your testing